# Rails, joining two tables with where clauses on each tabe

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, where-clause

I'm new to web development and rails, and I'm trying to construct a query object for my first time. I have a table Players, and a table DefensiveStats, which has a foriegn-key player_id, so each row in this table belongs to a player. Players have a field api_player_number, which is an id used by a 3rd party that I'm referencing. A DefensiveStats object has two fields that are relevant for this query - a season_number integer and a week_number integer. What I'd like to do is build a single query that takes 3 parameters: an api_player_number, season_number, and week_number, and it should return the DefensiveStats object with the corresponding season and week numbers, that belongs to the player with api_player_number = passed in api_player_number.

Here is what I have attempted:

```
class DefensiveStatsWeekInSeasonQuery
def initialize(season_number, week_number, api_player_number)
    @season_number = season_number
    @week_number = week_number
    @api_player_number = api_player_number
end

# data method always returns an object or list of object, not a relation
def data
    defensive_stats = Player.where(api_player_number: @api_player_number)
    .joins(:defensive_stats)
    .where(season_number:@season_number, week_number: @week_number)
    if defensive_stats.nil?
        defensive_stats = DefensiveStats.new
    end
    defensive_stats
end
```

end

However, this does not work, as it performs the second where clause on the Player class, and not the DefensiveStats class -> specifically, "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: players.season_number"

How can I construct this query? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Player.joins(:defensive_stats).where(players: {api_player_number: @api_player_number}, defensive_stats: {season_number: @season_number, week_number: @week_number})
```

**OR**

```
Player.joins(:defensive_stats).where("players.api_player_number = ? and defensive_stats.season_number = ? and defensive_stats.week_number = ?", @api_player_number, @season_number, @week_number)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect